Structure of the derivative of a Radical function in an algebraic form
I have this question where a particular form of a radical function, applied into the derivative by first principles formula without the limit reduces to a particular function

I substituted the f(x) and did a first conjugation/rationalization
and got this

Then I could see that part of it is like the derivative of the square root function times 'h' you could say

Looks like I may have to do a second rationalization.
Hope someone can let me know if this is the direction I should be going.
Hope someone can help.

There is no need to square the expression.  Start from $$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{a + b\sqrt{x + h} - (a + b\sqrt{x})}{h}$$ Simplify that expression, then rationalize the numerator.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Hi, I am showing the intermediate step of rationalizing the numerator, so it is not squaring the expression, that is the result of doing brute force of rationalizing. But I see now that one should simplify first.Thanks for your reply Taussig, I will try that.
